# WordPress widget outside installation folder

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

So for a very valid reason I am not going to get into the particulars on here and/or debate about, I am taking content controlled by WordPress into a sub folder not part of the WordPress install like post content by ID:

```
    <head>
<?php
// Include WordPress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
query_posts('showposts=10');
?>

</head>

<body>

<?php
$post_id = 21;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?>


</body>
```

and others similar to this, the issue I am facing now is I am trying to take a widget as the content in one of the posts, when I use a shortcode such as:

```
[do_widget id=gce_widget-2]
```

When that outputs using post_content it displays the shortcode as plain text. I've done quite a bit of searching around and am having difficulties finding how to grab the widget as well. Any help would be great!

Edit: I should mention the widget is a plugin widget not a WP core widget .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using do_shortcode instead of just echoing content.

Change

```
echo $queried_post->post_content;
```

to

```
$content = $queried_post->post_content;
echo do_shortcode($content);
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks.